# Upside down Inverted number triangle

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have some code

```
for i in range(0,11):
    for j in range(0,10-i):
        print(" ", end="")

    for k in reversed(range(0,i)):
        print(k, end="")
    print()`
```

which produces the following

```
     0
    10
   210
  3210
 43210
543210
......
```

I need it to print something like this

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6
    0 1 2 3 4 5
      0 1 2 3 4
        0 1 2 3
          0 1 2
            0 1
              0
```

I tried using `range(10,0,-1)` but this just prints the numbers on the "left side". Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The output on the command line starts from the left, so you could print blanks to format the output properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
for i in range(10,-1,-1):
for j in range(0,10-i):
    print("  ", end="")

for k in reversed(range(0,i)):
    print(k, end=" ")
print()
```

It produces the output:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
  8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
    7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
      6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
        5 4 3 2 1 0 
          4 3 2 1 0 
            3 2 1 0 
              2 1 0 
                1 0 
                  0
```